# Laravel 5.6 error in One to Many relationship

Tags: laravel-5.6

My One to Many relationship is like `One Sura` has many `ayah`.

Sura Model is like below

`Sura.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sura extends Model
{
    public function ayahs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Quran', 'surah_id', '_id');
    }
}
```

Quran Model is like below

`Quran.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quran extends Model
{

}
```

Sura Controller is like below

`SuraController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\Sura;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SuraController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Sura $sura)
    {
        return Sura::find($sura)->ayahs();
    }
}
```

My route is like below

`api.php`

```
Route::apiResource('/suras', 'SuraController');
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

I am trying to browse using below URL.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/suras/2
```

Comment: I think find takes an id, not a model instance

Comment: `return App\Model\Sura::find($sura)->ayahs;` try like this..

Comment: I am getting below error after using your solution. https://i.stack.imgur.com/acdxZ.png

Answer (score 1):

SuraController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\Sura;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SuraController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        return Sura::find($id)->ayahs();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use show(Sura $sura), then you must enter an object rather than an id on your URL.

Comment: I am getting below error after using your solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7GYH.png